# How to solve M queens when M<N using backtracking approach

Tags: algorithm, backtracking, n-queens

This is the [`N queens` problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eight_queens_puzzle). I know the `N queens` problem and its solution and I wrote a code in C++ programming language using backtracking approach:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int col[100];
int n;
int m;

bool check(int i,int k){
    for(int j=1 ; j<k ; j++){
        if(col[j] == i || i-k == col[j] - j || i+k == col[j]+j)return false;
    }
    return true;
}

void queens(int k){
    for(int i=1 ; i<=n ; i++){
        if(check(i,k)){
            col[k] = i;
            if(k == n){
                for(int j=1 ; j<=n ; j++)cout<<col[j]<<" ";
                cout<<endl;
            }
            else queens(k+1);
        }
    }
}

int main(){
    n = 4;
    queens(1);
}
```

But here is my question if we have **m** queens instead of **n** which **m < n** how can I solve this question with backtracking approach I think a few changes in my code would solve the problem but I'm not sure of it.

I googled it but found nothing so is there any backtrack solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You could make the function `queens` to have 2 parameters:

1. Column index you have currently reached (**num_column**)
2. Number of queens placed on the table (**`num_queens`**)

Now you must fix a column between **`[num_column, n]`** to place the queen.
Let **`(i, j)`** be the **`i`**'th row and **`j`**'th column (**`1 <= i <= n`** and **`num_column <= j <= n`**).

```
for j from num_column to n:
    for i from 1 to n:
        if check(i, j):
            col[j] = i
            queens(j + 1, num_queens + 1)
            //resetting the queen on j'th column
            col[j] = 0
```

You can stop the function when you reached **`num_queens == m`**.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is way more easier than you think! In regular `N-queen` problem, we iterate `k`, `n` times. So we can add our first queen at any place in the first column (between 1 till 8) and so on for other queens.

But if the queen count (`m`) is smaller than our chess size (`n`) we have to place that queen (our first queen) not only on the first column but everywhere (from 1 till 64) and do the same thing for other queens.

So the only thing you have to do is to iterate `k`, `n*n` times instead of `n` times.